# Алгоритм преобразования в постфиксную нотацию

Tags: c, алгоритм, польская-запись

Чтобы перевести в обратную польскую запись использую этот [алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C).
Возникли сложности с понимание следующих строчек  `(если оператор o1 право-ассоциированный) приоритет o1 меньше приоритета оператора, находящегося на вершине стека…`.Под право-ассоциированным оператором имелись в виду факториал и возведение в степень.Вопрос: как право-ассоциированный оператор может обладать более низким приоритетом , чем какой-либо другой оператор.У него же приоритет самый высокий